# How do I prevent Excel from only keeping the first data point of the series that I selected when using ctrl+shift+arrow?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

When adding a series to a chart in Excel, I typically click the first value, then use ctrl+shift+down to select large amounts of data. I do this for both the x and y values. However, Excel only saves the first value in both sets. The series data dialog box says the whole range is selected, but to the right of the box it says "= 0" instead of "= 0,1,2..." as it should (since multiple values are selected).

Then, when I click 'OK' to finish editing the series only one point is saved and the rest of the data is not displayed. If I go to edit the series, Excel has reverted the x and y values listed in the dialog box to just the first point instead of the whole range. How do I stop Excel from doing this?

The only thing I can do is manually drag+select and/or type in the range which is much more time consuming. I've talked with other people who have the same issue, but I cannot find anything on the internet about this. I would really like to be able to use ctrl+shift+arrows to select large amounts of data for a series, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this generally works for me. Have you tried restarting your computer? Do you use latest version of Excel?

Comment: Do you use "Shift+Arrow" ? Or "Ctrl+Shift+Arrow" ? @MátéJuhász , I always use "Shift+Arrow" , which has (luckily) always worked for me !

Comment: @prem the two are different shift+arrow extends selection by one cell, ctrl+shift+arrow extends it until end of range.

Comment: Do you have any customize shortcut keys? Do you use Windows or MacOS?

Comment: I have no custom shortcuts, on the latest version of Excel on Windows. Have tried restarting my computer but it hasn't fixed the issue. Shift+Arrow works, but it does still take a while to select large data ranges - that's why I was trying to use Ctrl+Shift+Arrow to jump to the end of the range as @MátéJuhász said! Ctrl+Shift+Arrow works to select the range but Excel will just not save the selected range in series data. It works perfectly fine in every other situation (formulas, copy+paste, etc).

Comment: Please post a screenshot how it looks like, I'd like to try your exact scenario

Answer (score -1):

You are using "Ctrl+Shift+Arrow" which will make MS Excel select only one additional cell at a time.

Use "Shift+Arrow" which will make MS Excel select multiple cells.

Details :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/select-cell-contents-in-excel-23f64223-2b6b-453a-8688-248355f10fa9